# Kendo UI Grid inline edit define custom values for min validation

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, inline-editing, custom-validators

I am using Kendo grid and want to validate one field's min value by another field from same record.

Meaning my data is like this :-

```
var courses = [{
    CourseID : 1,
    CourseName : "iPhone",
    MinAge: 12,
    MaxAge : 22,
    MinAgeThreshold : 10,
    MaxAgeThreshold : 30,
    StartDate: "12/10/2014",
},
{
    CourseID : 2,
    CourseName : "Android",
    MinAge: 12,
    MaxAge : 22,
    MinAgeThreshold : 10,
    MaxAgeThreshold : 30,
   StartDate: "12/10/2014",
}]
```

and I want to use MinAgeThreshold value in MinAge's validation min value, something like this:-

```
schema: {
               model: {
                 id: "CourseID",
                 fields: {
                    CourseID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    StartDate: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    CourseName: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    MinAgeThreshold: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    MinAge: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: MinAgeThreshold}                        },
                    MaxAge: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },

                 }
```

Is this possible somehow?

I tried to use in validation custom function like this

```
MinAge: {
                                type: "number",
                                validation: {
                                    required: true,
                                    minagevalidation: function (input) {
                                }
                            },
```

but I was not able to retrieve the values of MinAgeThreshold in minagevalidation function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like given below to give the custom validation message and **force the user to set value greater than the minimum value based on other input field in the same kendo grid.**

```
 MinAge: { type: "number",
                    validation: { 
                    required: true, 
                    MinAgevalidation: function (input) {
    if(input.is("[name='MinAge']") &&(parseInt($("input[type='text'][name='MinAge']").val()) < parseInt($("input[type='text'][name='UnitPrice']").val()))){
    input.attr("data-MinAgevalidation-msg", "MinAge should greater than MinAge threshold");

            return false;
    }

    return true;  
    }
```

[sample jsfiddle to set minimum value of one field based on other field's value .](http://jsfiddle.net/j54q0mrn/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have a solution for that kind of a problem. If you want to set the max of a field by the value of a different field you can add that to the grid edit method of your kendogrid.

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    edit: function(e){
        if ( e.container.find("input[data-find='value:MinAge']).length != 0 ){
            var numericTextBox = e.container.find("input[data-find='value:MinAge']).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
            numericTextBox.min(e.model.MinAgeThreshold);
        }
    }   
});
```

This will set the numerictTextBox of the MinAge input to min of the MinAgeThreshold that is in the dataItem of the row (model). That works with step, max, and so on as well. Edit is triggered when you enter the field. So if the initial value is 0 and your MinAgeThreshold is something else it will then switch to the MinAgeThreshold.